# Gnuplot tutorials/books/articles for learning and usage

Tags: reference, gnuplot

I have used gnuplot for some time, and I feel some lack of quality info on it. What are some good sources of reference on gnuplot? Which tutorials/books are the best to use in order to learn gnuplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually look no further than the [gnuplot tips (not so frequently asked questions)](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html)

This is the best site I have found and covers almost everything (from interaction with awk and sed to multiplots with multiple axes) with fully working examples.

Answer (score 3):

I have to say that Janert's book is excellent. After struggling with trying to use all the web resources out there, it imparts a sense of structure and how-to that is very welcome to a newbie:
[gnuplot in action](http://www.manning.com/janert)

Comment: Hi dan, you mistyped your hyperlink (you missed the t from Janert) I don't have privileges to change this myself, so maybe you could when you have time

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with gnuplot a lot lately and I really came to appreciate the pdf-manual: [PDF-Manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf)

It is well structured, as soon as you get the hang of it! And another advantage I see in it: After a while, when you spend some time reading it, you know where to find the definitions and your working with gnuplot is much more productive. Furthermore, it has many links to examples in the web.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the official manual-document is the most important one.

[gnuplot tips (not so frequently asked questions)](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html) is also worth a visit. There are many fundamental knowledge about gnuplot.

To get more advanced knowledgeS you may visit these blog [gnuplot surprising](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/). It talk about some advanced gnuplot tricks. For example, background color and image, shadowed curve and key ...